# Issues testing my Spring MVC Controllers

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have the following controller method. A user submits a search form with 4 input fields and has to fill in at least one of the field. If all the fields are empty (using the validator) then an error will be displayed on top of the form (in the same page).

Otherwise it will use the service method to look for users and display the results at the bottom of the form (in the same page). That is why in the if statement I return the same page as well as the end of the method because whatever happens the user is directed to the same page

```
@RequestMapping(value="/search", method={RequestMethod.POST})
    public ModelAndView searchUser(@ModelAttribute("searchUserDTO")SearchUserDTO searchUserDTO, BindingResult bindingResult, ModelMap modelMap){
        validate(searchUserDTO, bindingResult);
        List<BlueUser> users = new ArrayList<>();
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            modelMap.put("searchUserDTO", searchUserDTO);
            return new ModelAndView(VIEW_USERS, modelMap);
        } else {
            users = BlueUserService.findUsers(searchUserDTO.getMyName, searchUserDTO.getSSID(), searchUserDTO.getPostcode(), new Email(searchUserDTO.getMail()));
        }
        modelMap.put("searchUserDTO", users);
        return new ModelAndView(VIEW_USERS, modelMap);
  }
```

validator method

```
@Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        SearchUserDTO dto = (SearchUserDTO)target;
        if(dto.getMyName()==null && dto.getSSID() == null && dto.getPostcode() == null && dto.getMail()==null){
            errors.reject(EMPTY, "Please fill in the form");
        }
    }
```

I use `reject` to return error in the global scope and not on specific field and the following test method:

```
    public static final String BINDING_RESULT = BindingResult.class.getName() + '.' + "searchUserDTO";

   @Test
    public void searchUserPOST() throws Exception{
        MultiValueMap<String, String> paramMap = mockMVCTestUtil.createParamMap("myName", null,
                                                                                "ssid", null,
                                                                                 "postcode", null,
                                                                                  "mail", null);
        MvcResult mvcResult = this.mockMvc.perform(
                post("/search")
                        .params(paramMap))
                .andExpect(model().attributeExists("searchUserDTO"))
                .andExpect(model().attributeHasErrors("searchUserDTO"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())

                .andExpect(redirectedUrl(VIEW_USERS))
                .andExpect(forwardedUrl(VIEW_USERS))
                .andReturn();
        BindingResult bindingResult = (BindingResult) mvcResult.getModelAndView().getModel().get(BINDING_RESULT);
        assertNotNull(bindingResult);
        assertGlobalErrorMessage(bindingResult, "Please fill in the form");
    }
```

When I run the test method it fails and i get the following error messages:

```
Forwarded URL = null
Redirected URL = null
Cookies = []

java.lang.AssertionError: No errors for attribute 'searchUserDTO'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint inside public void validate(..) and inspect which of the attributes of target/dto is nonNull? Maybe SSID, mind the case.

Comment: @AlbertHendriks i have done that and attributes are Nulls

Comment: Does it work if you replace `errors.reject(EMPTY, "Please fill in the form");` by `errors.rejectAttribute("mail", "Please fill in the form");` and `.andExpect(model().attributeHasErrors("searchUserDTO"))` by `.andExpect(model().attributeHasErrors("mail"))` ?

Comment: Instead you also might try to just replace `EMPTY` by `"searchUserDTO"` and call `rejectAttribute` instead of `reject`.

Comment: 1. What is mockMVCTestUtil? 2. Could there be a casing issue: `ssid` vs. `dto.getSSID()`?